# Undefined index when data with file path updating?

Tags: php, forms, file, codeigniter, upload

I have a file upload form it works perfect when new file upload.But index error when update. At update data, i want that if new file select it will upload new file and update the data with that file path(which worked perfect) but when updating (just want to update old data) it gives index error. i am using codeigniter.

html form :

```
<section>
<label class="label" for="FileUpload">
Activity    Image File</label>
<label for="file" class="input input-file">
<div class="button">
<input id="fileToUploadactivity" name="fileToUploadactivity" type="file" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" > <!-- onchange is use to put the file name on below input field -->
Browse
</div>
<input type="text" name="SelectedFileName" id="SelectedFileName" value="<?php echo $value['file_path']; ?>" readonly>
```

in php

```
//if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUploadactivity']['tmp_name'])){ // also error in here

$newfile =  $_FILES["fileToUploadactivity"]["tmp_name"];
if (!empty($newfile)) {

// new file uploding code

}else{

// old data upload
}
```

error

> Message: Undefined index: fileToUploadactivity

Comment: Can you give the HTML code between, and including, the <form></form> tags.

Comment: Check form enctype, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

Comment: everything is ok when i upload new file.But when i do update it gives the above mentioned error. I also assume that i added enctype="multipart/form-data" on form attributs. My problem is just when updating old file path. if i select new file when updating it is ok .